# Scala flatMap over getConstructors method (reflection)

Tags: scala, reflection, flatmap

I'm trying to iterate over the constructors of a given class using reflection. 
The problem is that I need to do something to each element and then return only the ones that matches some predicate. the following code throws exception

```
classOf[String].getConstructors.flatMap(x=> doSomething(x); if(predicate(x)) Some(x) else None)
```

The exception:

```
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_] => Iterable[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[?0(in value $anonfun)]] forSome { type ?0(in value $anonfun) }
 required: java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B]
```

I'm not sure if this can be done with for comprehension because I need to call do something on each element(not just for the ones that holds the predicate):

```
for{
    x <- c.getConsturctors
    //doSomething(x) ?? 
    if predicate(x)
}yield{
    //doSomething(x) - only for the ones that holds the predicate
    x
}
```

Calling c.getMethods works so I'm guessing it has something to do with the return type(Array[Methods] vs Array[Constructor[_]])...?

**Answer** :

flatMap - Alexey Romanov answer

for comprehension(with the help of pamu):

```
for{
    x <- c.getConsturctors
    _ = doSomething(x)
    if predicate(x)
}yield x
```

Comment: Need more information about `doSomething` and `predicate`  to tell whats exactly wrong

Comment: It doesn't really matter, lets say doSomething prints x and predicate just returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to details of type inference implementation, Scala ends up with `Iterable[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[A]] forSome { type A }` where you want `Iterable[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[A] forSome { type A }]` (or shorter, `Iterable[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_]]`). Annotating the type should work:

```
c.getConstructors.flatMap { x =>
  doSomething(x)
  (if (predicate(x)) Some(x) else None): Option[Constructor[_]]
}
```

but I must admit I don't see *why* the problem arises.

Comment: ya I guess it has something to do with implicits.. still interesting to know if anyone knows why..

Answer (score 1):

Use `collect` instead of `flatMap` and then returning `Some`, `None`

```
classOf[String].getConstructors.toList
  .collect { case elem if predicate(elem) => doSomething(elem) }
```

Using flatMap

```
classOf[String].getConstructors.toList.flatMap { elem =>
  doSomething(elem);
  if (predicate(elem)) {
    List(elem)
  } else List()
}
```

Using for-comprehension

```
for {
 elem <- classOf[String].getConstructors.toList
 _ = doSomething(elem)
 val result = if (predicate(elem) List(elem) else List()
} yield result
```

Comment: it works (but the if should be inside the case clause so doSomething will be called on each iteration regardless of the predicate result). Anyway I'm looking for a way to solve the issue using flatMap or for comprehension.

Comment: Regarding the flatmap- I don't want list but option. The for is useful but I would change that to: ...if (predicate(elem))} yield elem

Comment: "I don't want list but option" Option will be converted to a list anyway by the implicit to satisfy the expected type.